# Problema con colisiones de un softbody en unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, game

estoy desarrollando un juego donde son muy importantes las colisiones con otros objetos. He descargado un prefab de un softbody (como un cubo de gelatina) que tiene colisiones perfectas con el suelo, un plano, pero al moverlo contra otros objetos (como paredes, cubos o lo que sea) interactua con ellos pero acaba atravesandolos. No sé como solucionar esto, si me echais una mano me vendria de perlas. Adjunto el prefab que he descargado por si quereis hacer pruebas.

Edito
Este es el proyecto completo que descargue
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BybYdop7N8_0NDY3dFpINUhjaUU/view

Comment: Bienvenido Javier de prefrencia que el codigo este en la pregunta puedes editarla y mostrarlo para ayudarte con la duda

Comment: He dejado el proyecto completo en el post

Comment: ahora no puedo ver el proyecto, pero revisa si ese softbody tiene un meshcollider, como tal no interactua correctamente con las fisicas. La solucion suele ser cambiarle dicho meshcollider por uno tipo capsule o box

Answer (score 0):

A tu elemento: Add Component -> Physics -> Rigidbody

Con esto, las leyes de la física se aplican, en este caso, la gravedad hará que caiga tu elemento.

Siempre es bueno ver la documentación oficial, por eso, aquí te dejo un link donde explican a detalle lo que acabo de mencionar.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/rigidbodies